# Python 2 TypeError : argument of 'int' type is not iterable

Tags: python

this is the code that i was ruuning, from this i get this type error how to change thus error

```
file_path = os.path.join(folder_path,filename)
f = open(file_path,'a+')
index = -1
for slicelist in slicelists:
    index += 1
    sentences = slicelist.split('\n')
    if sentences[0] == '\r' or sentences[0] == '':
        del sentences[0]
    if sentences == []:
        continue
    if sentences[-1] == '':
        del sentences[-1]
    if sentences[-1] == '\r':
        del sentences[-1]
    labellist = labellists[index]
    for labels in labellist:
        if 1 in labels:
            label = 1
        else:
            label = 0
```

This is the output :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data_preprocess.py", line 43, in <module>
    if 1 in labels:
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

How to overcome this problem???

Comment: It looks like `labellist` contains at least one integer. Verify that there are no integers in this list, and that it only contains objects which can be iterated over - such as lists.

Comment: @user10987432
i didnt understand!!

Comment: what does your `labellist` look like? Can you post it in a comment or update your question?

Comment: @user10987432 i have updated my question please look at it!!

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `"In"`in `if statement` you must have iterable items. But it has only one item, as your taken care of iteration in `for statement`

you Can do it this way , it's very simple

```
if 1 in lablelist:
    lable=1
else:
    label = 0
```

Comment: @angel What do you mean by error changed .. is there any error now ?

Comment: actually no error is showng right now, but all the input got labelled as 0, thats another problem